# Character reference "&#x1F" is an invalid XML character

Tags: xml

Can anyone please tell me how to solve the following XML Exception?

```
Character reference &amp;#x1F is an invalid XML character
```

I have a XML file with the character &#x1F, When I try to parse this XML file I'm getting this Exception. Is there any way to resolve this?

The part of my code is like this...

```
File f = new File("sample.xml");
dom = db.parse(f);
```

I'm getting exception when I'm calling the function `parse()`. I also tried with UTF8 encoding, and got the same exception.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank u in advance!!!

Comment: Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579112/how-to-escape-special-characters-when-retrieving-data-from-database

Comment: although you tagged your question with `xml`, I think your problem is related to the programming language you're using to parse your XML: what is it? Java? Please tag the question appropriately. Also. it may be helpful if you post the exception that you get, the snippet of XML that you're trying to parse, and the code that you're using (`dom = db.parse(f)` doesn't say much: what is `db`?)

Comment: @perumal, although this question is very old it is of particular interest to me. Would you mind to clarify as MarcoS suggests? It would be very helpful to me and others.

Answer (score 10):

As Michael Kay commented: There are more valid characters in XML 1.1 than in XML 1.0. In case the XML has a prolog that declares version 1.0 it might be sufficient to change the prolog from

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.1"?>
```

If there are still invalid characters, you must decide how to deal with them. [Streamflyer](http://code.google.com/p/streamflyer/#Fix_invalid_characters_in_XML_streams) will ease your task.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a class that extends FilterReader to skip invalid XML characters. See [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150627043152/http://info.tsachev.org/2009/05/skipping-invalid-xml-character-with.html).

Answer (score 1):

The XML file is invalid, and the parser is telling you so. The control character decimal 31, hex 0x1F, can't appear in XML source. You need to have a look at the file and see what's going on.

Comment: Yes you are right. The XML file is invalid but it is the response from a server, So I can't edit the XML file instead I want to write the code which will escape this kind of invalid XML characters before parsing.... Any idea please???

Comment: Actually, x1F is valid in XML 1.1 (provided it appears as a numeric character reference), so using a 1.1 parser may provide a way forward. In general however, if people are going to send you stuff that's not valid XML then they might as well not bother using XML at all, and the right solution to handling invalid XML is always to fix the program that created the stuff. By all means try to repair it, but first try to get the supplier to fix it.

Comment: @Michael: I assumed that the actual byte 0x1f was appearing in the source. But if indeed it's just the character ref, then yeah, absolutely, @perumal, just use a better/newer parser.

Comment: Alternatively, if there's no way to get the file fixed and it really does contain junk characters, then you may be able to, for example, write a class that extends `FilterInputStream`, overrides the `read()` methods, and drops or substitutes for the junk characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list a valid character entities.  Perhaps from the context of your xml you can determine what it should be:

http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/ncrs.html

Comment: Yes steve, I understood, but the XML file is the response from a server. I can't edit the XML, but want to do something to solve this..... What shall we do? Any idea?

Comment: You are getting invalid data.  As others have pointed out: You can reject it or cleanse it.  I see no other options.